# Calling Java methods asynchronously using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I've been trying to get familiar with JNI and its functionality. I am trying to figure out how could I possibly keep reference to the Java environment. I am first calling native method that stores creates "NewGlobalRef" from the jobject and it works fine for a while. But then all the sudden I receive fatal error and log. I am pretty sure garbage collector removes something, even if I am keeping reference to the object all the time in both sides.

What I am doing atm is this

I call native method

```
myCoolObject.nativeMethod(otherCoolObject);
```

I am keeping reference to otherCoolObject all the time on java side. What the native method does is

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj , jobject otherCoolObject) {
    cout << "Called native method!" << endl;
    coolObj = env->NewGlobalRef(otherCoolObject);
    clazz = (*env).GetObjectClass(coolObj;
    callbackEnv = env;
    methodId = (*env).GetMethodID(clazz, "callback", "(II)V");
    jint x = 1;
    jint y = 2;
    (*callbackEnv).CallVoidMethod(coolObj, methodId, x, y);
}
```

and I can call the method after this for a while but all the sudden it gives me fatal error I told you about

Comment: I am new to jni, what is the aim of using callbackEnv ? Can't we keep using (*env).CallVoidMethod(coolObj, methodId, x, y); ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reuse your JNIenv, cause it's specific to the function that created it (it's thread, scope and all).
for getting a valid JNIenv for calling an java method from your callback you have to
use JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs() and AttachCurrentThread()

more information here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html

Comment: If I try to use JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs() I only get "undefined reference to `_imp__JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs@12'" error code above

Comment: found this thread may be useful: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t130983-call-java-method-from-c-jni.html

Comment: After I created global reference it started working, but after a while it gives new fatal error

Comment: You're the best! Got it working after playing with it for second(I am not too good with C languages :< )